# Is there a way to call registry ONLY one time and extract various keys values

Tags: c#, registry

I am basically reading below registry path,

```
SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft
```

But I have different `sub keys` and `keys` to read.

example

1. `Version` under `SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\DataAccess`
2. `NodePath9` under `SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\ENROLLMENTS\\ValidNodePaths`
3. etc.

Currently I am able to read it one-by-one, but what are the ways so that I need to go the registry ONLY one time and I can do all other manipulation in C# code?

Can I read all information at once (so that ONLY one call to registry) till `SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft` and do rest work in C# code?

```
var X1 = GetRegistryValue("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\DataAccess", "Version");
            var X2 = GetRegistryValue("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\ENROLLMENTS\\ValidNodePaths", "NodePath9");



 private static string GetRegistryValue(string subKey, string keyName)
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subKey))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                if (key.GetValue(keyName) != null)
                {
                    return (string)key.GetValue(keyName);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *Why* do you want to make only one call to the registry?

Comment: just to avoid multiple calls

Comment: There's no need to worry about it.  Only worry about it if it's actually a problem.

Comment: OK, just wonder if there is a way

Comment: @Archer, by the way, can you post your answer again?

Comment: I've undeleted it for you.  If it helps it helps, but you don't need to worry about something like performance where registry access is concerned.  If it *is* a performance issue then you probably shouldn't be using the registry for what you're doing!  Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

The `OpenSubKey()` method returns a registry key, so you could create a common one first and then pass it into the `GetRegistryValue()`...

```
private static RegistryKey GetCommonKey(string subKey)
{
    return Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subKey);
}

private static string GetRegistryValue(RegistryKey commonKey, string subKey, string keyName)
{
    using (commonKey.OpenSubKey(subKey))
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            if (key.GetValue(keyName) != null)
            {
                return (string)key.GetValue(keyName);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

// usage

var commonKey = GetCommonKey("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft");
var version = GetRegistryValue(commonKey, "DataAccess", "Version");
var nodePath = GetRegistryValue(commonKey, "ENROLLMENTS\\ValidNodePaths", "Version");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm seeing `OpenSubKey` in both method. Are you sure there is only ONE call to registry?

Comment: No - there is multiple calls to the registry and there always will be.  I'll delete this and post a comment under your question instead.